# Node express find data in filter

Tags: node.js, express

I am following some tutorial but there is some problem in finding value in array . This is how my code looks

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

const courses = [
  {id: '1', name: 'ITCS1'},
  {id: '2', name: 'ITCS2'},
  {id: '3', name: 'ITCS3'},
];

app.get('/api/courses/:id', (req, res) => {
  const course = courses.find(c => c.id === parseInt(req.params.id));
  if (!course) res.status(404).send('Course not found for given id');
});

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Listening on port ${port}`));
```

when i am loading this url `http://localhost:5000/api/courses/1`  `its giving me course not found for given id`

But the expected result is `{id: '1', name: 'ITCS1'}` Because id 1 is in courses array. So why he is showing error because id is matching with array  ?

Answer (score 1):

It's work with this code:

```js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

const courses = [
  {id: '1', name: 'ITCS1'},
  {id: '2', name: 'ITCS2'},
  {id: '3', name: 'ITCS3'},
];

app.get('/api/courses/:id', (req, res) => {
  const course = courses.find(c => c.id === req.params.id);
  if (!course) res.status(404).send('Course not found for given id');
});

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Listening on port ${port}`));
```

The reason why you get an error, because you're using `parseInt`.

And in your `course`, **your id is a string, not integer**. So, you should not to use `parseInt`.

If you want to using parseInt, please update your course array, an **make your id is an integer**, not a string.

**An example:**

```js
const courses = [
  {id: 1, name: 'ITCS1'},
  {id: 2, name: 'ITCS2'},
  {id: 3, name: 'ITCS3'},
];
```

Now, you can use parseInt(req.params.id) and it's will working fine.

I Hope it's can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Apply parseInt for both sides

```
courses.find(c => parseInt(c.id) === parseInt(req.params.id))
```

or use `==` not `===`

```
courses.find(c => c.id == req.params.id)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have type `string`  of `id` field. And you are matching it with `int` type field. Make both field `types` either make both of them `int` or `stirng`.

```
courses.find(c => c.id === req.params.id.toString())
```

Or

```
courses.find(c => parseInt(c.id) === parseInt(req.params.id))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because you’re comparing a string and integer strictly. You could either use two equal signs or change the data types to match.

Answer (score 0):

That's because `c.id` is a `string` but you are converting the `id` parameter to `int` with `parseInt(req.params.id)`. `'1'===1` is `false`. Use this:

```
app.get('/api/courses/:id', (req, res) => {
  const course = courses.find(c => c.id === req.params.id);
  if (!course) res.status(404).send('Course not found for given id');
});
```

`===` operator returns true only if the operands have the same value and type. Using `==` operator would work in your case but it's not recommended as it may lead false positives.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you're using strict equal and you `courses` has it's **id** as a string.

You can either change your `courses` object to:

```
const courses = [
  {id: 1, name: 'ITCS1'},
  {id: 2, name: 'ITCS2'},
  {id: 3, name: 'ITCS3'},
];
```

or use double equal:

```
const course = courses.find(c => c.id == req.params.id);
```

or parse both:

```
const course = courses.find(c => parseInt(c.id) === parseInt(req.params.id))
```

But I suggest changing the data type of `courses.id` and using the strict equal. But that's only in my opinion. You can learn more about strict and loose equality [here](https://codeburst.io/javascript-double-equals-vs-triple-equals-61d4ce5a121a)